# subprocess.Popen running infinite loop with py2exe

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, py2exe

I'm trying to use py2exe to compile a python script into an executable.
I've set up the setup.py file just like it's described in documentation:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['agent.py', 'test.py'])
```

The agent.py file simply uses subprocess.Popen to open another script:

```
import sys
import subprocess

print 'is this working?'

child = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'test.py'])
```

The test.py file is

```
while 0 == 0:
    print 'test'
```

When running this as a python script, it works fine. When running as a py2exe-compiled executable, it does not run.

When I try to change the file reference in agent.py from 'test.py' to 'test.exe', running the compiled agent.exe simply prints 'is this working?' on an infinite loop. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That didn't quite work, but all I had to do was replace your answer with the full path name. Thanks! This worked:

```
app_path = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(sys.executable), 'test.exe'))
child = subprocess.Popen(app_path)
```

Answer (score 2):

`sys.executable` points to `agent.exe` instead of `python.exe` when run as compiled executable. You need to change your `Popen` to:

```
child = subprocess.Popen(['test.exe'])
```

when running compiled executable. You can use `hasattr(sys, "frozen")` to determine whether you're in frozen (py2exe) or not (Python script) mode.

Comment: That didn't quite work, but all I had to do was replace your answer with the full path name. Thanks!

This worked:

    app_path = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(sys.executable), 'test.exe'))
    child = subprocess.Popen(app_path)